# Proving $B=(A\cap B^c)\cup(A^c\cap B)\iff A=\emptyset$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I would like to know how to prove the second part of the biconditional I want to prove that $B=(A\cap B^c)\cup(A^c\cap B)\iff A=\emptyset$

I already demonstrated this part:

If $A=\emptyset$ then $A\cap B^c=\emptyset$ and since $A^c=\emptyset^c=U$ and since $B\subseteq U$ then $B\cap U=B$ and $B\cap A^c=B$ and therefore $(A\cap B^c)\cup(A^c\cap B)=\emptyset\cup B=B$ which is a part of the mathematical proof

But how can I prove that if $B=(A\cap B^c)\cup(A^c\cap B)$ then $A=\emptyset$ ?

I appreciate your time and help

Comment: If $A,B$ are subsets of a set $X$ you can try to prove that $B=(A\cap B^c)\cup (A^c \cap B) \implies A^c=X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $B=(A\cap B^c\cap B)\cup(A^c\cap B\cap B)$, then notice that:

- $B=B\cap B=(A\cap B^c\cap B)\cup(A^c\cap B\cap B)=A^c\cap B$; therefore you have $A^c\supseteq B$, i.e. $A\subseteq B^c$.
- $\emptyset=B\cap B^c=(A\cap B^c\cap B^c)\cup(A^c\cap B\cap B^c)=A\cap B^c$. By the previous point, $A\cap B^c=A$.